# debug, неверный вывод при определенном значении

Tags: ассемблер, отладка

хочу кое - что уточнить...
В debug пишу программу, которая должна выполнять действия: ((1+[201])*([202]+[203])) / ([203]-19)
На картинке я описала все действия, но, когда я вычитаю из знаменателя 19, то ответ выводит неверный. На картинке я отняла только единицу (sub bh, 1), если делать так, то все работает. Но с 19 -- нет. Помогите пожалуйста, я и правда не понимаю, что не так..

```
-a 100
mov al, [201]
mov ah, [202]
mov bh, [203]
add al, 1
add ah, bh
imul ah
sub bh, 19
idiv bh
mov [200], al
hlt
```

Comment: `когда я вычитаю из знаменателя 19, то ответ выводит неверный` - какой ожидаете, какой получается? Учитывайте, что отладчик показывает числа в 16-ричной системе. И еще, приведите код программы в вопросе в текстовом виде.

Comment: привела код в текстовом формате. Я ввожу числа так: ((1+1) * (0+20)) / (20-19), в итоге должно получиться 40, а в шестнадцатеричном коде -- 28, а там выводится 109... Если в знаменателе вычитать от ячейки [203] число 1 (допустим), и будет выражение ((1+1)*(1+1)) / (2-1) ответ будет 4 и выводится  верно, 4.

Comment: В данном случае idiv делит регистр ax (пару регистров ah и al) на переданный ему операнд. Поэтому перед делением нужно очистить ah (т.к. это старшая часть регистра ax). Т.к. у вас в ah осталось число от предыдущих вычислений, то результат деления получается совсем не тот что вам нужен.

Comment: т.е. после умножения, стоит добавить mov ah, 0?

Comment: после добавления ничего не меняется...

Comment: Я несколько раз перепроверил, в обоих вариантах в переменную результата в конце записывается 28h. Но это так совпало, что в ah ноль перед делением, поэтому результат правильный. Скрин, ячейка с результатом обведена зеленым: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGdOK.png